# Facebook Login with Android SDK Debugging

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, android-logcat

I'm using Facebook SDK 3 for Android. I use the example from Get Started -> Sample Login app on developers.facebook.com. After login try I get App Page with

> Tabu is misconfigured for Facebook login.

My problem is that in Logcat I do not get any info what is wrong. I should get hash error info or anything else but it's totally quiet.

I did change

```
com.facebook.android.Util.ENABLE_LOG
```

to true but still no luck.

Comment: did you add your `Hashkey` on facebook app?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem I did but generally I don't know what is wrong since the Facebook Logger doesn't give me any info on anything. As I red in internet it should.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can look at below post,

[talhakosen.com/2012/11/22/facebook-api-for-android/](http://talhakosen.com/2012/11/22/facebook-api-for-android/)

Comment: Don't know why and how but hash generation from this tutorial worked for me... Crazy ;)

Comment: it made me happy that you like my tutorial :)